# Excel Crashing when doing multiple PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a macro that filters data depending in a large worksheet and copies it to several worksheets if the destination worksheet is empty. When testing it, the first destination worksheet gets data with no problem, but at the next iteration of filtering and copying the data, Excel crashes. Here's my code:

```
Sub Script()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim data, sht1, sht2, sht3, sht4, sht5 As Worksheet

Set data = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHT1")
Set sht2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHT2")
Set sht3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHT3")
Set sht4 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHT4")
Set sht5 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHT5")

If IsEmpty(sht1.Range("A1")) Then
With data.Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="CR1"
.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="X"
.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Y"
.SpecialCells(12).Cells.Copy sht1.Range("A1")
End With

End If

If IsEmpty(sht2.Range("A1")) Then
With data.Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="CR2"
End With

data.Range("A1").SpecialCells(12).Cells.Copy sht2.Range("A1")

End If

If IsEmpty(sht3.Range("A1")) Then
With data.Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="CR3"
End With

data.Range("A1").SpecialCells(12).Cells.Copy sht3.Range("A1")

End If

If IsEmpty(sht4.Range("A1")) Then
With data.Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="CR4"
End With

data.Range("A1").SpecialCells(12).Cells.Copy sht4.Range("A1")

End If

If IsEmpty(sht5.Range("A1")) Then
With data.Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="CR5"
End With

data.Range("A1").SpecialCells(12).Cells.Copy sht5.Range("A1")

End If

If data.FilterMode Then data.ShowAllData
MsgBox "Process Completed", 0

End Sub
```

I already tried by adding the `.Cells` after the `SpecialCells` part, and running each section independently. The problem starts after the CR1 filtered content is pasted into sht1, then the next filtering and pasting crashes.

It would be of great help if someone could offer some insight. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

From past experience, using Excel to manipulate a large amount of data is not a good idea and is prone to experiencing crashes which you cannot fix.

You are better off assigning the value of the entire range to a variable. You end up with a two dimensional array that you can play with programmatically to filter. You can then store whatever you want to transfer into 2D array, which you can then assign to the value of a range.

This strategy is way faster and avoids crashes.

To be more radical, you may simply ressort to using a database. MS Access for example, for a quick and dirty solution.